# SVG mask not working with multiple transforms

Tags: svg, mask

I have several avatar frames(on chairs around a round table) that I'm generating dynamically in react. I'm trying to add a `clip-path` to the frames which will clip the image according to the frame's shape.

I have the (generated) code below for one of the frames, which doesn't seem to work even though the clipping region falls exactly on the image(checked using chrome's inspector). I have tried clipping/masking it with a clip-path as well as mask(included in the code below). It'd be great if somebody could explain why this isn't working?

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 2000 2000">
  <g class="avatar_container">
    <defs>
      <symbol id="avatarFrame" viewBox="-12 -8 135 135">
        <path d="M55.5 121.217l8.313-11.856A50.55 50.55 0 00106.049 59.5 50.55 50.55 0 0055.5 8.951 50.55 50.55 0 004.951 59.5a50.55 50.55 0 0042.237 49.861z"></path>
      </symbol>
      <use id="frame-def" xlink:href="#avatarFrame" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></use>
      <mask id="frame-mask" x="0" y="0" width="2200" height="2200">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="2200" height="2200" fill="#000"></rect>
        <use x="1067.525" y="100" transform="rotate(315,1117.525,400)" xlink:href="#frame-def" fill="#fff"></use>
      </mask>
      <clipPath id="frame-clip">
        <use x="1067.525" y="100" transform="rotate(315,1117.525,400)" xlink:href="#frame-def"></use>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g class="avatar" transform="rotate(315,1117.525,400)" mask="url(#frame-mask)">
      <image xlink:href="https://via.placeholder.com/100" x="1067.525" y="100" transform="rotate(-315,1117.525,150)" width="100" height="100"></image>
    </g>
    <use id="frame" class="avatar_frame" xlink:href="#frame-def" transform="rotate(315,1117.525,400)" x="1067.525" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="#545454" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></use>
  </g>
```

Comment: It's because you are cutting outside the image. In order to debug it: at the end of the document use the content of the mask and next use the rotated image

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you for your comment, I figured it out. I was rotating the clipping region twice. I removed the extra transforms and all good. :)